# Extract TLD from hostname string

Tags: javascript, next.js, getserversideprops

I have the following hostnames and they TLDs.

- dev.sitename.com **(.com)**
- sitename.com **(.com)**
- sitename.co.uk **(.co.uk)**
- dev.sitename.co.uk **(.co.uk)**
- staging.sitename.k34.com **(.com)**
- local.sitename.com:3000 **(.com)** - *(Is used on local webserver virtual host for testing)*
- local.sitename.co.uk:3000 **(.co.uk)**- *(Is used on local webserver virtual host for testing)*

These hostnames are fetched from NextJS `getServerSideProps` via

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const hostname = ctx.req.headers.host;
};
```

I can't seem to use a method than can handle subdomains and second level domains like `.co.uk` and potentially handle port numbers?

What I initially had was

```
const getTld = (hostname: string) => {
  return hostname.split(/\./).slice(-1).join('.');
}
```

but for

```
getTld("sitename.co.uk")
```

it returns `uk`, not `co.uk`

for

```
getTld("local.sitename.co.uk:3000")
```

it returns `uk:3000`, not `co.uk`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Technically, `co.uk.` isn't a TLD, `uk.` is

Comment: The TLD of `sitename.co.uk` is `uk`. A TLD can't have a dot in it, by definition.